# How to query data from interval rows (with only one limit per row) in a relational database

Tags: mariadb

I have a set of tables in my database that contain information about products, delivery methods, delivery costs, and market areas. I am trying to write a query that will find the cheapest delivery method for a list of products, based on their delivery cost unit.

The relevant tables are:

- `products`: contains product information, including `id` and `delivery_cost_unit` columns
- `delivery_methods`: contains delivery method information, including `id`, `code`, and `visible` columns.
- `delivery_costs`: contains delivery cost information, including `id`, `delivery_method_id`, `market_area_id`, `min_delivery_cost_units`, and `delivery_cost` columns.
- `market_areas`: contains market area information, including `id` and `name` columns.

For each product, I need to find the delivery method that has the lowest `delivery_cost` for its `delivery_cost_unit` value.
The query will be executed once per area, and the area is given as input.
Additionally, a list of product ids can be provided as input.

The `delivery_costs` table defines delivery cost intervals for various combinations of delivery method, market area, and min_delivery_cost_units. The min_delivery_cost_units column defines the minimum value of delivery_cost_unit that the delivery cost applies to, and there are multiple rows for each delivery method and market area, with increasing values of min_delivery_cost_units.

I have tried writing a query, but I'm not getting the expected results. Here is a query that correctly returns a list of products, together with the available delivery method ids:

```sql
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.delivery_cost_unit,
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT dc.delivery_method_id)
        FROM
            delivery_costs AS dc
            INNER JOIN delivery_methods AS dm ON dm.id = dc.delivery_method_id
        WHERE
            dc.market_area_id = 10
            AND p.delivery_cost_unit >= ( SELECT MIN(min_delivery_cost_units) FROM delivery_costs WHERE delivery_method_id = dc.delivery_method_id) 
            AND p.delivery_cost_unit < (SELECT MAX(min_delivery_cost_units) FROM delivery_costs WHERE delivery_method_id = dc.delivery_method_id)
            AND dm.visible = 1
            AND dm.code NOT IN('pickup', 'email')
    ) AS available_delivery_methods
FROM
    products AS p
WHERE
    p.id IN(100,101,102);
```

The data I'd like to get back from the query would be something like this:

| id | delivery_cost_unit | cheapest_delivery_method_id | cheapest_delivery_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 20 | 10 | 150 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

but cheapest_delivery_method_id would be a *bonus*. I really only need the `cheapest_delivery_cost` property next to the product `id`.

The "problematic" table for me to wrap my head around is the `delivery_costs` one.

For clarification, I'm showing some data sample below:

| delivery_method_id | market_area_id | min_delivery_cost_units | delivery_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88 | 11 | 0 | 999 |
| 88 | 11 | 31 | 999 |
| 88 | 11 | 51 | 1190 |
| 88 | 11 | 101 | 1290 |
| 88 | 11 | 151 | 1390 |
| 88 | 11 | 201 | 1490 |
| 88 | 11 | **251** | **1490** |
| 88 | 11 | 301 | 4990 |
| 88 | 11 | 351 | 5990 |
| 88 | 11 | 601 | 11900 |
| 88 | 11 | 901 | 12900 |
| 88 | 11 | 1301 | 14900 |
| 88 | 11 | 2101 | 14900 |
| 88 | 11 | 2401 | 15900 |
| 88 | 11 | 2501 | 15900 |
| 88 | 11 | 2901 | 16900 |
| 88 | 11 | 3901 | 21900 |
| 88 | 11 | 4901 | 24900 |
| 88 | 11 | 6901 | 44900 |
| 88 | 11 | 10001 | 89900 |
| 88 | 11 | 9999999 | 99900 |

I've also managed to get the minimum `delivery_cost` for the available `delivery_method_id` values, but I couldn't get it for the correct interval, meaning that for a given product with `delivery_cost_unit` = 300, the `delivery_cost` for the example delivery_method with the `id` = 88 should **not be 999** but **1490**.

I'm using **MariaDB v10.6.4**.

Comment: Can you share simple data from all the tables

Comment: Here's a WIP fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/_3urPLC5

Comment: Here's a more complete one: https://dbfiddle.uk/ZykbjgBG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [LEAD](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lead/) to add `max_delivery_cost_units` to the `delivery_costs` and concatenated the fields together as we can only return one value from the correlated subquery.

```sql
SELECT p.*, (
    SELECT CONCAT_WS('::', delivery_method_id, delivery_cost, code)
    FROM (
        SELECT dc.*, dm.code, LEAD(min_delivery_cost_units) OVER (PARTITION BY delivery_method_id ORDER BY min_delivery_cost_units) -1 AS max_delivery_cost_units
        FROM delivery_costs dc
        JOIN delivery_methods dm
            ON dm.id = dc.delivery_method_id
        WHERE dc.market_area_id = 10
        AND dm.visible = 1
        AND dm.code NOT IN ('pickup', 'email')
    ) dmc
    WHERE p.delivery_cost_unit BETWEEN dmc.min_delivery_cost_units AND dmc.max_delivery_cost_units
    ORDER BY delivery_cost ASC
    LIMIT 1
) cheapest_delivery_method
FROM products p;
```

Here's your updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/owTe8xHD).